# Edge detection shader using a color picking texture (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures

I'm writing a small 3D application where I want to highlight selected objects with colored edges. I render the normal scene into two color attachments using a FBO. The first one contains only the normal color output and the second one stores the picking IDs of all visible objects in the scene (color picking).
Now I want to pass those two textures into my fragment shader and output either the normal color value from the first texture or yellow, if this fragment lies on the edge of the current object. This is how the relevant part of my shader looks like:

```
uniform sampler2D picking_texture;
uniform sampler2D color_texture;
uniform float pickingID;
uniform float width;
uniform float height;

...

// texture coordinate delta
float dxtex = 1.0 / width;  // texture width
float dytex = 1.0 / height; // texture height

// compare neighboring texels in the picking texture (edge detection)
float nLeft   = texture2D(picking_texture, gl_TexCoord[1].st + vec2(-dxtex, 0.0)).r;
float nRight  = texture2D(picking_texture, gl_TexCoord[1].st + vec2( dxtex, 0.0)).r;
float nTop    = texture2D(picking_texture, gl_TexCoord[1].st + vec2( 0.0, dytex)).r;
float nBottom = texture2D(picking_texture, gl_TexCoord[1].st + vec2( 0.0,-dytex)).r;
float sum = nLeft+nRight+nTop+nBottom;

if(sum != 4.0 * pickingID)
{
    finalColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

In my opinion this should work, but there are two problems:

- the object with ID 0 is colored as usual
- everything else is colored completely yellow

What I thought so far is that sum is always 0 and that way all objects with pickingID higher than 0 are colored yellow. But this means that the lookup in the picking_texture always returns 0. So there is probably something wrong with my textures (binding, texCoords, etc.) but I couldn't figure out what. The color_texture works as expected.

This is what I am doing in the CPU-part of the program:

After linking and binding the shaders:

```
// set locations of the textures
texture_location0 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram->programId(), "color_texture");
glUniform1i(texture_location0, 0);
texture_location1 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram->programId(), "picking_texture");
glUniform1i(texture_location1, 1);
```

Before drawing the scene:

```
// set textures
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTex);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pickingTex);
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Where is your `#version` directive?

Comment: I have none :D
How do I know which version to take?

Comment: `#version 120` should be OK.  Generally in the absence of an explicit `#version` you'll end up with `110`.

Comment: Thx, I already tried #version 130 and it works as before.

Comment: Hard to tell without full code, but I would start by verifying both textures by rendering them to quads. Then I would verify every uniform is being sent in correctly either by using a glsl debugger, or rendering out some debug information in the frag shader.

Comment: Ok, I could solve the problem. The problem was not with the code in general, but with my approach to solve it. I had to pass one more uniform to the fragment shader to be able to reliably differentiate between all cases. Thx for the help!